# Where are secrets kept in Telegram Bots?

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot

I'm developing a Telegram Bot which will make HTTP request to an external API which requires an API key.

Is there a special place wherein secrets like this should be kept in Telegram Bots? The one that Telegram API or SDK may provide?

Or is it normal to store them in the source code hardcoded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not store them in the source code, if you send that code to somebody later, you might forget to remove the key.

Instead, put it in a `.env` file, and load it into memory using `os.environ`.

How the contents of `.env` could look like:

```
API_KEY=SECRET_HERE123
```

```py
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import os

load_dotenv()

print(os.environ["API_KEY"])
```